# How to search for Creative Commons in the Youtube API [C#, .Net]

Tags: api, youtube

I am using the Youtube APi 3.0 for .Net and this [code sample][1]. Everything works perfect but I do not know how to search fot CC.

```
        var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Q = "Google"; 
        searchListRequest.VideoLicense = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoLicenseEnum.CreativeCommon;
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#search_by_keyword

Answer (score 0):

The answer was so simple...

```
var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Type = "video";
        searchListRequest.Q = searchword; // Replace with your search term.
        searchListRequest.VideoLicense = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoLicenseEnum.CreativeCommon;
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
```